# How to put compiled apk to jenkins job artifacts?

Tags: android, jenkins

I need to copy compiled apk file to job artifats to be able to download it directly from page of job if it was successful.
Now i have compiled apk file in folder build/apk/MyProject-release.apk
I'm using Gradle as a build tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a post build action for this. Just configure "archive the artifacts" with the path from your question. Nothing else needs to be done.